# structure of xstate config which has condion included & which can be used in vue-kanban pkg

Tags: vue.js, kanban, xstate

I'm trying to create xstate Machine which has condition to be check when moving to another state(Using **VueJs**).

issue is the way tried which is not working with **vue-kanban(https://github.com/BrockReece/vue-kanban)** pkg

below is my sample state machine config :

```
stateMachineConfig: {
        id: "kanban",
        initial: "on-hold",
        states: {
          "on-hold": {
            on: {
              IN_PROGRESS:"in-progress",
            }
          },
          "in-progress": {
            on: {
              RELINQUISH_TASK: "on-hold",
              PUSH_TO_QA: "needs-review",
            },
          },
          "needs-review": {
            on: {
              REQUEST_CHANGE: "in-progress",
              PASS_QA: "approved",
            },
          },
          approved: {
            type: "final",
          },
        },
      },
```

this is the UI of kanban(https://ibb.co/6rWxN0F)

after i changing above config by adding condition to "on-hold" state  then i can't move to anywhere from "on-hold" state.

below is the new config:

```
const searchValid = (context) => {
  console.log(`context.status `, context);
  return true;
};

stateMachineConfig: {
        id: "kanban",
        initial: "on-hold",
        states: {
          "on-hold": {
            on: {
              PICK_UP: [
              {
                target: "in-progress",
                cond: searchValid
              }
            ]
            }
          },
          "in-progress": {
            on: {
              RELINQUISH_TASK: "on-hold",
              PUSH_TO_QA: "needs-review",
            },
          },
          "needs-review": {
            on: {
              REQUEST_CHANGE: "in-progress",
              PASS_QA: "approved",
            },
          },
          approved: {
            type: "final",
          },
        },
      },
```

any help to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your machine using the XState visualizer and all works properly, you can check it [here](https://stately.ai/viz/75740843-daaa-4c4b-a0e9-99ddc71edef1)